# How can I see which process is causing another process to be blocked in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I know `SHOW PROCESSLIST` can show me which processes are `Locked`, but how do I determine which process is blocking it?  Is that info available?  I know in SQLServer there's a column that tells you which process is blocking another process.  Is there something similar here?

Comment: you *might* have better luck over at http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's a long running query in "sending data" state that is using tables needed by locked queries.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is the longest running query on the same table that your query is running on. But, it depends on the storage engine that you are using. If you are using InnoDB, you won't have this issue.